# Search for summation formula

Tags: summation

Is there any closed formula for the sum  $ ~\sum_{k = 1} ^ {n} r^k k^r ~$  where $~r~$ is an integer?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think these are related to the Stirling numbers, but, upon looking them up, the relation is not clear to me. Thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: The exact formula at <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739315/is-there-a-general-formula-for-sum-limits-n-0n-1-qnnm/4739554#4739554>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum corresponds to the following polylogarithm:

$$ \sum_{k = 1} ^ {n} r^k k^r = \operatorname{Li}_{-r}(r)$$

Comment: But polylogarithm is a sum of infinite series, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. There are no closed forms in the strict sense for the general polylogarithm.

Comment: So there' little hope to find exact formula even for this specific sum?

Comment: No undefined power sum have an exact formula @Igor, see Falhauber formula. The best approach maybe a desired level of precision on computing, something like the [h function](http://mhhspace.org/mathjax/indefinite%20integration/Indefinite%20Integration%20of%20the%20Gamma%20Integral.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately, exact formulas exist only for some specific polylogarithms. For pratical purposes, you could consider the use of fast computation algorithms approximating $\operatorname{Li_n}(z)$ (see for example http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37229-enhanced-computation-of-polylogarithm-aka-de-jonquieres-function).